# Call to a member function toArray() on null

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get value of meta key from table called site.management
this table

=>http://www.mediafire.com/file/pa4gs0pbwpoalqj/Homemetakey.PNG/file

```
 public function index()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('site_managements')) {
            $homepage = SiteManagement::getMetaValue('homepage');
            if (!empty($homepage['home'])) {
                $sections = Helper::getPageSections();
                $selected_page = Page::find($homepage['home']);
                $page_data = $selected_page->toArray();
                $page = array();
                $home = true;
                $page['id'] = $page_data['id'];
                $page['title'] = $page_data['title'];
                $page['slug'] = $page_data['slug'];
                $page['section_list'] = !empty($page_data['sections']) ? Helper::getUnserializeData($page_data['sections']) : array();
                $description = $page_data['body'];
                $page_meta = SiteManagement::where('meta_key', 'seo-desc-' . $homepage['home'])->select('meta_value')->pluck('meta_value')->first();
                $page_banner = SiteManagement::where('meta_key', 'page-banner-' . $homepage['home'])->select('meta_value')->pluck('meta_value')->first();
                $show_banner = SiteManagement::where('meta_key', 'show-banner-' . $homepage['home'])->select('meta_value')->pluck('meta_value')->first();
                $breadcrumbs_settings = SiteManagement::getMetaValue('show_breadcrumb');
                $show_breadcrumbs = !empty($breadcrumbs_settings) ? $breadcrumbs_settings : 'true';
                $show_banner_image = false;
                if ($show_banner == false) {
                    $show_banner_image = false;
                } else {
                    $show_banner_image = true;
                }
                $banner = !empty($page_banner) ? Helper::getBannerImage('uploads/pages/' . $page_banner) : 'images/bannerimg/img-02.jpg';
                $meta_desc = !empty($page_meta) ? $page_meta : '';
                $type = Helper::getAccessType() == 'services' ? 'service' : Helper::getAccessType();
                $slider_section = '';
                $slider_style = '';
                $slider_order = '';
                foreach ($selected_page->meta->toArray() as $key => $meta) {
                    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $meta['meta_key'], $matches);
                    $meta_key_modify = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $meta['meta_key']);
                    if ($meta_key_modify == 'sliders') {
                        $slider_section = Helper::getUnserializeData($meta['meta_value']);
                        $slider_style = !empty($slider_section['style']) ? $slider_section['style'] : '';
                        $slider_order = !empty($slider_section['parentIndex']) ? $slider_section['parentIndex'] : '';
                    }
                }
                $categories = Category::latest()->get()->take(8);
                $skills = Skill::latest()->get()->take(8);
                $locations = Location::latest()->get()->take(8);
                $languages = Language::latest()->get()->take(8);
                $page_header = '';
                $currency   = SiteManagement::getMetaValue('commision');
                $symbol = !empty($currency) && !empty($currency[0]['currency']) ? Helper::currencyList($currency[0]['currency']) : array();
                if (file_exists(resource_path('views/extend/front-end/pages/show.blade.php'))) {
                    return View::make(
                        'extend.front-end.pages.show',
                        compact(
                            'symbol',
                            'page_header',
                            'page',
                            'meta_desc',
                            'banner',
                            'show_banner',
                            'show_banner_image',
                            'show_breadcrumbs',
                            'selected_page',
                            'sections',
                            'type',
                            'slider_style',
                            'slider_section',
                            'description',
                            'slider_order',
                            'home',
                            'categories',
                            'skills',
                            'locations',
                            'languages'
                        )
                    );
                } else {
                    return View::make(
                        'front-end.pages.show',
                        compact(
                            'symbol',
                            'page_header',
                            'page',
                            'meta_desc',
                            'banner',
                            'show_banner',
                            'show_banner_image',
                            'show_breadcrumbs',
                            'selected_page',
                            'sections',
                            'type',
                            'slider_style',
                            'slider_section',
                            'description',
                            'slider_order',
                            'home',
                            'categories',
                            'skills',
                            'locations',
                            'languages'
                        )
                    );
                }
            } else {
                if (file_exists(resource_path('views/extend/front-end/index.blade.php'))) {
                    return view('extend.front-end.index');
                } else {
                    return view('front-end.index');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and am getting this error

```
Call to a member function toArray() on null
```

every thing was working fine but an interruption happened in my DB and I resorted it but home index after login gives me the mentioned error

```
Call to a member function toArray() on null
```

*(the project on laravel 5) *
what is the problem here?

Comment: In which line does that error occur? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: `->toArray()` is a collection function and your calling to from a null value so before call this function check variable is null or not

Comment: $page_data = $selected_page->toArray(); ,  6th line on my function

Comment: $selected_page = Page::findOrFail($homepage['home']);
$page_data = $selected_page->toArray();
please use findOrFail method, it will throw exception when if returns null. and there are so many performance issues in the code.

Comment: @KamleshPaul its a key values if you checked the link its the DB table has values

Comment: what are you getting $homepage['home'] variable

Comment: @ShaileshMatariya i 404 error

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/4wylljta2p3b5xq/error.PNG/file @Yogendra

Comment: what are you getting in $homepage['home'] is 22 as id or your  meta key

Comment: 404 error is ok it means that for that id, the findOrFail was null so it threw an exception, resulting in 404

Comment: @Yogendra , bhucho ,22 meta value is "home" that should call index not 404 every and directions is correct and you see }else{} has other redirection if failed to get the correct one but not gives 404 actually am confusing why this happening every things was prefect

Comment: if you want to handle it on your own then use `find()` instead of `findOrFail()` but you will have to check if value exists in that variable then use inArray(), here check `$page_data is empty($selected_page)` then return with error that the value is empty or execute further, findOrFail throws exception I guess modelnotfoundException you can even catch it execute your conditions

Comment: @bhucho the point is when am comment all of the code and return view index home page it working fine